# RestKit XML Mapping issue with nested elements

Tags: xml, restkit, response

I'm using RestKit .22, and having problem mapping XML response to entity. Everything works and I get 200OK, but objects arent mapped correctly. In XML response there is a root element "response", under it an array of "events".

```
<response>
  <meta>...</meta>
  <events>
      <event>...// data that I'm after reflected in the entity. </event>
  </events>
</response>
```

My code:

```
- (void)setupRestKitWithBaseURL:(NSURL *)baseURL{
[AFNetworkActivityIndicatorManager sharedManager].enabled = YES;

RKObjectManager *objectManager = [RKObjectManager managerWithBaseURL:baseURL];
[RKMIMETypeSerialization registerClass:[RKXMLReaderSerialization class] forMIMEType:RKMIMETypeXML];
[objectManager setAcceptHeaderWithMIMEType:@"application/xml"];

// Initialize managed object store
NSManagedObjectModel *managedObjectModel = [NSManagedObjectModel mergedModelFromBundles:nil];
RKManagedObjectStore *managedObjectStore = [[RKManagedObjectStore alloc] initWithManagedObjectModel:managedObjectModel];
objectManager.managedObjectStore = managedObjectStore;

NSEntityDescription *entity = [[managedObjectStore.managedObjectModel entitiesByName] objectForKey:@"Event"];
RKEntityMapping *eventMapping = [[RKEntityMapping alloc] initWithEntity:entity];
[eventMapping addAttributeMappingsFromArray:@[ @"title" ]];
[eventMapping addAttributeMappingsFromDictionary:@{
                                                   @"id" : @"remoteID",
                                                   @"date_tbd" : @"dateToBeDecided",
                                                   @"time_tbd" : @"timeToBeDecided",
                                                   @"datetime_utc" : @"start",
                                                   @"venue.name" : @"location"
                                                   }];

RKResponseDescriptor *eventIndexResponseDescriptor = [RKResponseDescriptor responseDescriptorWithMapping:eventMapping method:RKRequestMethodGET pathPattern:@"events" keyPath:@"response" statusCodes:RKStatusCodeIndexSetForClass(RKStatusCodeClassSuccessful)];
[objectManager addResponseDescriptor:eventIndexResponseDescriptor];


[objectManager addFetchRequestBlock:^NSFetchRequest *(NSURL *URL) {
    RKPathMatcher *pathMatcher = [RKPathMatcher pathMatcherWithPattern:@"events"];
    NSDictionary *argsDict = nil;
    BOOL match = [pathMatcher matchesPath:[URL relativePath] tokenizeQueryStrings:NO parsedArguments:&argsDict];
    if (match) {
        return [NSFetchRequest fetchRequestWithEntityName:@"Event"];
    }
    return nil;
}];

[managedObjectStore createPersistentStoreCoordinator];
NSString *storePath = [RKApplicationDataDirectory() stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Example.sqlite"];
[managedObjectStore addSQLitePersistentStoreAtPath:storePath fromSeedDatabaseAtPath:nil withConfiguration:nil options:nil error:nil];
[managedObjectStore createManagedObjectContexts];
managedObjectStore.managedObjectCache = [[RKInMemoryManagedObjectCache alloc] initWithManagedObjectContext:managedObjectStore.persistentStoreManagedObjectContext];
```

}

console:

```
[63994:2621733] I restkit.network:RKObjectRequestOperation.m:220 GET 'http://api.seatgeek.com/2/events?format=xml&lat=39.75&lon=-104.984&per_page=500&range=10mi&taxonomies.name=sports' (200 OK / 2 objects) [request=0.0002s mapping=0.0018s total=0.0035s]
```

So I get 2 events loaded which are nested elements of "response" element: "meta" & "events", but not actual events under "events" array, which is what i need. Help greatly appreciated.
Thanks

***UPDATE***

Besides Wain's answer I've also changed these values to be value.text:

```
[eventMapping addAttributeMappingsFromDictionary:@{
                                                   @"title.text" : @"title",
                                                   @"id.text" : @"remoteID",
                                                   @"date_tbd.text" : @"dateToBeDecided",
                                                   @"time_tbd.text" : @"timeToBeDecided",
                                                   @"datetime_utc.text" : @"start",
                                                   @"venue.name.text" : @"location"
                                                   }];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to specify the full key path to drill down to the mapping level. From your description it should be `response.events.event` but you have just set `response`.

Comment: thanks alot for promt answer. Ive tried specifying response.events, but still same issue, 200OK, but not mapped. Ive enabled logging RKLogConfigureByName("RestKit/*", RKLogLevelTrace), and see xml objects coming down in console, but nothing is mapped. Help greatly appreciated. Many thanks

Comment: What is the dictionary log that it says will be mapped? I don't use XML (ever) so it might be that the key path should also have `.event`

Comment: really appreciate your help. i've sent request with only 1 id, so response is smaller(1obj), here is the console log: http://pastebin.com/22gnwFE8
many thanks

Comment: *UPDATE* - sorry sent wrong pastebin before, this is the correct one: http://pastebin.com/nKEYMV9E

tried keyPath:@"response.events.event"  still same prob, i also specify pathPattern:@"events", and 

 RKPathMatcher *pathMatcher = [RKPathMatcher pathMatcherWithPattern:@"events"];

Comment: i have updated my code to the following:
 RKResponseDescriptor *eventIndexResponseDescriptor = [RKResponseDescriptor responseDescriptorWithMapping:eventMapping method:RKRequestMethodGET pathPattern:@"events" keyPath:@"response.events" statusCodes:RKStatusCodeIndexSetForClass(RKStatusCodeClassSuccessful)];

and now getting this in console: http://pastebin.com/siMJMZcf

Comment: Yeah, you need `.event` on the keypath